# How to Invalidate JWT token on logout , spring boot API running on multiple nodes in Azure for scalability a

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, jwt, authorization

How to Invalidate JWT token on logout , springboot API running on multiple nodes in Azure for scalability.

Maintaining JWT token in memory blacklist on logout event will fail if we increase the nodes on azure to scale it up
case: if we blacklist token on one node but request comes on another node with that blacklisted JWT token , then blacklisting will not work
case2: of in memory blacklist object size grows bigger it may cause Memory related issue

please suggest working approach

Comment: We can use a distributed caching layer. Prime candidates are [memcached (`memcached.org`)](https://memcached.org/) and [redis (`redis.io`)](https://redis.io/).

Comment: Go for redis and store the invalidate tokens.

Comment: The distrubed chaching layer is good, but also consider the design of your application. It looks like you're trying to mix the session/cookie based approach with a jwt based approach. Session based authentication is stateful, jwt based approach is designed to me stateless. As soon as a valid jwt is produced, that user can approach for the lifetime of that jwt (and refresh if needed). Blacklisting is then only needed when for example a monitoring tool finds suspicious activity. Don't blacklist all logged out tokens, but let them expire. Also let a job cleanup your blacklist for expired jwts.